# Passing uint64_t from C++ to R: Hilbert Mapping - xy2d function

Tags: c++, c++11, r, coordinate-system, rcpp

I have been working with Rcpp to perform a forward and backward [Hilbert Mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve#Applications_and_mapping_algorithms).  Below is an implementation based on [this code](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/hilbert_curve/hilbert_curve.cpp).

My application is in genomics and I may be dealing with enormous datasets, which necessitates the use of very large integers for indices, so I found [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49015493/integer64-and-rcpp-compatibility) for passing large integers to R using Rcpp and the bit64 R package and incorporated it after the `for` loop.

The `xy2d()` function works properly.  My interest is on your thought regarding the code AFTER the `for` loop, which prepared the result for passage back to R. Please let me know what you think  :)

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
# include <bitset>
# include <cstdint>
# include <ctime>
# include <iomanip>
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//****************************************************************************80
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector xy2d ( int m, uint64_t x, uint64_t y )
//
//****************************************************************************80
{
  uint64_t d = 0;
  uint64_t n;
  int rx;
  int ry;
  uint64_t s;

  n = i4_power ( 2, m );

  if ( x > n - 1 || y > n - 1) {
    throw std::range_error("Neither x nor y may be larger than (2^m - 1)\n");
  }

  for ( s = n / 2; s > 0; s = s / 2 )
  {
    rx = ( x & s ) > 0;
    ry = ( y & s ) > 0;
    d = d + s * s * ( ( 3 * rx ) ^ ry );
    rot ( s, x, y, rx, ry );
  }

  std::vector<uint64_t> v;
  v.push_back(d);
  //v[0] = d

  size_t len = v.size();
  Rcpp::NumericVector nn(len);         // storage vehicle we return them in

  // transfers values 'keeping bits' but changing type
  // using reinterpret_cast would get us a warning
  std::memcpy(&(nn[0]), &(v[0]), len * sizeof(uint64_t));

  nn.attr("class") = "integer64";
  return nn;
}
```

This post will be followed up shortly with another post regarding the `rot()` function, and well as the reverse `d2xy()` function

Comment: @422_unprocessable_entity:  The Hilbert mapping function works with no problems.  I am seeking advice on the code AFTER the for-loop in which I prepare the results to be passed to R.  "Hilbert Mapping - xy2d function" makes that unclear.  I feel that my original title was better, would you agree?

Comment: Welcome to CR. I edited the question title because I thought it can be improved as recommended [here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2438/47826). Anyway it is a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Because we write C++, there's no reason to declare (most) variables at the beginning of the scope of your function. For example, all of `d`, `rx`, `ry` and `s` have been declared for no reason if you happen to throw and exit the function.
- You don't need `s` after the for-loop, so it should be local to the loop only. Similar for `rx` and `ry`.
- Make use of shorthand operators like `/=` and `+=`.
- You can make `v` const and initialize it with a suitable constructor, in this case `std::vector<uint64_t> v(1, d);` initializes `v` to hold one element equal to `d`. But really, as it stands, I see no point in using an array here if you just have a single value (I suspect your example is incomplete and not representative of your real use case, which is a shame).
- Because `len` can be const, make it const. This protects from unintended errors and possibly allows the compiler to perform more optimizations.
- As a general comment, avoid saying `using namespace std;`, it's not good for you.
- I don't know the interface of `Rcpp::NumericVector`, but might you initialize it directly in the spirit of `const Rcpp::NumericVector nn(v.cbegin(), v.cend())`, for instance?